# Building gradle for Wear App failed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, wear-os

I tried to create a Android Wear project in the Android Studio. It can't seem to build the gradle file, all I get is following:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':wear'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':wear:_debugCompile'.
> Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.support:wearable:+.
 Required by:
     Browser:wear:unspecified
> Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+.
 Required by:
     Browser:wear:unspecified
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441321/android-wear-project-gradle-sync-fails

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is a known issue. Hope it will be solved in the next days.

- open the Android SDK Manager
- Go to the menu Tools->Manage Add-On Sites and add this url to the user defined sites: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon-play-services-5.xml (note: the menu is the menu of the SDK manager, not Android Studio)
- Reload and update the Google Play services to the new versions.

Now gradle should be able to solve the dependency and download the missing modules and the compilation should complete.

Comment: Not working for me. In short I'm pretty sure this gradle thing is crap. Of course coming from Eclipse I guess that's expected. Seriously though everything used to be so much easier. I have Google Play Services showing (v 18) in SDK manager. Still getting this error.

Comment: Could not agree more about gradle, @Fraggle, it is a massive productivity drain. In my case, I had a problem where I was running the SDK Manager from the command line, not realizing that it was a separate installation of Android vs. the one that is built in to Android Studio, hope that helps.

Comment: One more gotcha: The SDK Manager menu may not appear until you un-focus and re-focus the Manager. Then you will have access to the Packages and Tools menu items.

Answer (score 3):

If all of these didn't work for you, check out the instructions at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72454
For me, I was simply missing Google Repository from the extras section in the sdk manager.

add the repo at https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon-play-services-5.xml and then make sure you've installed Google Repository.
It should be available on the extras section of sdk manager

Comment: The two missing libraries are downloaded as part of the Google Repository. The android gradle plugin looks in this local Maven repository to resolve these two dependencies. If you hover over Google Repository in the SDK Manager it will tell you location of the local Maven repository if you want to check whether the libraries are actually there. You need at least version 9 of the Google Repository to get the wearable library.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after installing AndroidStudio 0.8.9 in Ubuntu 14.10 recently. The solution was to go to SDK Manager and install Google Play Services and Google Repository. They do not seem to be installed by default.